# Custom NER model is not returning any entitiy and giving blank iterations

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to learn how to train a custom NER model, earlier it was training all fine, but not sure what happened, now it is not returning any entity, and giving blank iterations:

```
Training_data = [
    ('what is the price of McVeggie?', {'entities': [(21, 29, 'FoodProduct')]}),
    ('what is the price of McEgg?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'FoodProduct')]}),
    ('what is the price of McChicken?', {'entities': [(21, 30, 'FoodProduct')]}),
    ('what is the price of McSpicy Paneer?', {'entities': [(21, 35, 'FoodProduct')]}),
    ('what is the price of McSpicy Chicken?', {'entities': [(21, 36, 'FoodProduct')]}),
] 
# Testing sample data       
testing_sample='what is the price of McAloo?'

import random
from pathlib import Path
import spacy
from tqdm import tqdm
from spacy.training.example import Example

model = None
output_dir=Path("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Folder1")
iterations = 20

# loading a blank model

if model is not None:
    nlp = spacy.load(model)
    print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
else:
    nlp = spacy.blank('en')
    print("Created blank 'en' model")

# Setting up the pipeline

if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ner_pipe = nlp.add_pipe('ner',name='ner_pipe',last=True)
else:
    ner_pipe = nlp.get_pipe('ner')

# Adding entities labels to the ner pipeline

for text, annotations in Training_data:
    for entity in annotations.get('entities'):
        ner_pipe.add_label(entity[2])

# Getting names of other pipes to disable them during training

other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
other_pipes

# Training NER model

with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    for itn in range(iterations):
        print("Iteration Number:" + str(itn))
        random.shuffle(Training_data)
        losses = {}
        for text, annotations in Training_data:
            doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
            example = Example.from_dict(doc, annotations)
            nlp.update([example], drop=0.2, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
        print(losses)
```

This code was able to train the entities earlier may be 3-4 days back, but today while checking it is not training, and giving blank iterations:

```
Iteration Number:0
{}
Iteration Number:1
{}
Iteration Number:2
{}
```

also while testing I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: [E109] Component 'ner_pipe' could not be run. Did you
> forget to call `initialize()`?

Earlier it was giving the following data when tested and that is what I am looking for as well:

```
Entities [('McVeggie', 'FoodProduct')]
Entities [('McEgg', 'FoodProduct')]
Entities [('McChicken', 'FoodProduct')]
Entities [('McSpicy Paneer', 'FoodProduct')]
Entities [('McSpicy Chicken', 'FoodProduct')]
```

I am kind of lost, can I please get some help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be you are removing the pipe by the wrong name factory_name instead of name.

You name it 'ner_pipe' then check the names for 'ner' instead of 'ner_pipe'

```
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner_pipe']
```

This seems like it would fix a part of your issue.  I don't get the error.

Full source I tried it against below:

```
Training_data = [
    ('what is the price of McVeggie?', {'entities': [(21, 29, 'FoodProduct')]}),
    ('what is the price of McEgg?', {'entities': [(21, 26, 'FoodProduct')]}),
    ('what is the price of McChicken?', {'entities': [(21, 30, 'FoodProduct')]}),
    ('what is the price of McSpicy Paneer?', {'entities': [(21, 35, 'FoodProduct')]}),
    ('what is the price of McSpicy Chicken?', {'entities': [(21, 36, 'FoodProduct')]}),
] 
# Testing sample data       
testing_sample='what is the price of McAloo?'

import random
from pathlib import Path
import spacy
from tqdm import tqdm
from spacy.training.example import Example

model = None
output_dir=Path("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Folder1")
iterations = 20

# loading a blank model

if model is not None:
    nlp = spacy.load(model)
    print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
else:
    nlp = spacy.blank('en')
    print("Created blank 'en' model")

# Setting up the pipeline

if 'ner_pipe' not in nlp.pipe_names:
    ner_pipe = nlp.add_pipe('ner',name='ner_pipe',last=True)
else:
    ner_pipe = nlp.get_pipe('ner_pipe')

# Adding entities labels to the ner pipeline

for text, annotations in Training_data:
    for entity in annotations.get('entities'):
        ner_pipe.add_label(entity[2])

# Getting names of other pipes to disable them during training

#here ensure you use what you named it above for the name (not the factory_name which comes first)
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner_pipe']
other_pipes
print( other_pipes)
# Training NER model

with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    for itn in range(iterations):
        print("Iteration Number:" + str(itn))
        random.shuffle(Training_data)
        losses = {}
        for text, annotations in Training_data:
            doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
            example = Example.from_dict(doc, annotations)
            nlp.update([example], drop=0.2, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
        print(losses)
```

Comment: Hi @Carter tried it but still getting the similar output

Comment: Hmm I feel like you might be missing pieces of the code. I can run this in a notebook and get this output:
Created blank 'en' model
[]
Iteration Number:0
{'ner_pipe': 27.61744576692581}
Iteration Number:1
{'ner_pipe': 15.330301206558943}
Iteration Number:2
{'ner_pipe': 6.208103255590686}
Iteration Number:3
{'ner_pipe': 4.201002557246172}
Iteration Number:4 (Repeasts up to 19)
.